# How can I use grep to extract all IP addresses contained in all the files within a directory and sub-directories?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a directory heirarchy full of text files containing (among other things) IP addresses. I want to build a list of all addresses referenced in all files in this directory and all subdirectories.

These addresses should be reasonably easy to identify using a regular expression, but I'm unsure of how to construct the command such that it will scan all files. So...

How might I use `grep` to build such a list?

Comment: Files don't "have IP addresses". The question does not make sense as written.

Comment: @user2864740: I think OP wants to find IP addresses in text form within text files

Comment: Why did this get 5 downvotes? This is a valid question minus the fact he didn't really **try** anything

Answer (score 5):

Just use grep recursively:

```
grep -r 'yourRegularExpression' .
```

**Mind** the dot at the end. It tells grep to start with current folder!

Edit: Since you only want the IP adresses, you can use -o parameter which will return you only the parts matching the regex. So something along the lines of this:

```
grep -roE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' .
```

should do the thing. (The -E parameter is an extended regexp, but I guess you are familiar with that).

Another edit: as ScottMcGready pointed out, I am assuming you have IP addresses you are searching for within text files and not in some weird formatting.

Comment: That's assuming the IP addresses are contained within text files and not in some weird formatting (might be worth adding that to your answer as an assumption!).

Comment: Ah yes. I absolutely agree! I didn't take that into account. I have edited my post, thank you for pointing it out.